# LeakCanary EditText.mContext

Tags: android, leakcanary

I have such a leak. I know SemClipboardManager.mContext is the exception
Сan be this interpreted SemClipboardManager.mPasteListener as SemClipboardManager.mContext and ignore this?

```
GC ROOT com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager$2.this$0 (anonymous subclass of android.sec.clipboard.IClipboardDataPasteEvent$Stub)
references com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager.mPasteListener
references android.widget.TextView$TextViewClipboardEventListener.this$0
references android.widget.EditText.mContext
leaks com.ivolve.sitespecs.activity.UsingCameraActivity instance
```

Or it is a leak and I need to find a solution EditText.mContext?